# startAnimating is not working inside the IBAction of a button press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having a strange problem.I am having a button , and on pressing the button I am  doing

the following

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {

    [ _spinner startAnimating];//where _spinner is a ActivityIndicator

    [self showResult];

}

-(void) showResult{

    sleep(10);

    resultText.text=@"Hi..Sorry.It has been a long wait";

}
```

But the spinner never starts animating , even  though the showResult method gets called

properly. I feel this very strange . When I put [_spinner startAnimating] in the viewDidLoad

it works perfect. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sleep method get called on the main thread causing UI to hang, that's why you aren't able to see the activity indicator

one way to do this:

```
- (IBAction)actionbuton:(id)sender {

    [_activity startAnimating];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundProcess) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) backgroundProcess{

    sleep(4);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processingDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) processingDone{

    [_activity stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Ok I got the point . But what will be the solution in my case ?

Comment: performSelectorAfterDelay or performSelectorInBackground, do the long work there ( thats better ) THEN call main thread again

Comment: Now with the introduction of GCD , we can handle it better using GCD I feel

Answer (score 0):

1. First start your acivity inside button press method.
2. Then after call your showResult method in timer.
3. I think that will resolve your problem.
4. Also remove Sleep from showResult.